# Problem in Covert ( image,line break,Numbers) from blob into string on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, contentdocument, contentnote

I have written a code to convert the blob content into string to display it on Visulaforce page.Its working.But I couldn't able to show the image.I mage is also converted as string like :

```
<img
src="https://virtusa1230-dev-ed--c.ap5.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=0687F000000Kok4QAC&amp;
```

and also numbers are coming like:

```
 "<ol><li>1.a</li><li>2.b</li><li>3.c</li></ol>" this.
```

and there is no space between 2 paragraph.This is the view I got
[image]

It should come like :
[image]

I have attached my code below.Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
public static List<String> getContent() {

    String RelatedTo = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    String cid;
    Blob myBlob;
    String p;
    String s;
    String q;
    List<String> notes = new List<String> ();


    List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlId = [Select ContentDocumentId From ContentDocumentLink Where LinkedEntityId = :RelatedTo]; 
        for(ContentDocumentLink c: cdlId){
            cid = c.ContentDocumentId;
        List<ContentNote> cids = [Select Title, Content From ContentNote Where id = :cid];
        for(ContentNote cn: cids){
                myBlob = cn.Content;
                s = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(myBlob)).toString().replace('<p>' ,'\r\n');
                notes.add(s);
        } 
    }

    System.debug(notes);
    return notes;
```

Comment: What does your Visualforce page do to display this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to try is this in your Visualforce page for each string in the list:

```
<apex:outputText value="{! content } escape="false"/>
```

as the [apex:otuputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) documentation offers the (rather confusingly explained) attribute option of:

> **escape**
>  Boolean
>  A Boolean value that specifies whether
>   sensitive HTML and XML characters should be escaped in the HTML output
>   generated by this component. If you don’t specify escape="false", the
>   character escape sequence displays as written. Be aware that setting
>   this value to "false" may be a security risk because it allows
>   arbitrary content, including JavaScript, that could be used in a
>   malicious manner.

Also note that I would expect that this:

```
s = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(myBlob)).toString()...
```

could be replaced with this:

```
s = myBlob.toString()...
```

Comment: Really great !!!. Its working .Thank you so much. Everything is displaying as I expected.

Comment: @Jury You are welcome.